Drizzle ORM: Nested object in select query
My code is
    const feedbacks = await drizzleClient
        .select({
            ...getTableColumns(feedbackFirst),
            project: {
                ...getTableColumns(project),
            },
            userFrom: {
                ...getTableColumns(users),
                userAbout: {
                    ...getTableColumns(userAbout),
                    avatar: {
                        ...getTableColumns(avatars),
                        photo: {
                            ...getTableColumns(photos),
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        })
        .from(feedbackFirst)
        .innerJoin(project, eq(project.prid, feedbackFirst.prid))
        .innerJoin(users, eq(users.uid, feedbackFirst.uidFrom))
        .innerJoin(userAbout, eq(userAbout.uid, users.uid))
        .innerJoin(avatars, eq(avatars.uid, users.uid))
        .innerJoin(photos, eq(photos.phid, avatars.phid))

There is an error near avatar
Object literal may only specify known properties, and photo does not exist in type


Despite of the type error, the query result is correct, with all nesting. How to fix the type error? And is it possible?
env
webstorm 2023.3.4
ts 5
node 21.4.0
macos sonoma 14.4


I don't know about your specific error but your use of spreading ...getTableColumns(xxx) really helped me be able to return nested relationships correctly, like Eloquent style because I ordering on the relationship isn't supported, I had to use the select() style but the joins wouldn't go inside of the parent object, now they are. Thank you very much for the inspiration mate!

@mick-davies, It's great that my issue helped you
